# Solve the recurrence $a_n=7a_{n-1}-10a_{n-2}$ where $a_{0}= 3$ and $a_{1}=3$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence $a_n=7a_{n-1}-10a_{n-2}$ where $a_{0}= 3$ and $a_{1}=3$

how can a $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ both equal $3$?

Comment: Why shouldn't $a_0$ and $a_1$ both equal $3$?

Comment: It means that $a_2 = 7\cdot 3 - 10\cdot 3 = -9$, and you just go from there.

Comment: Since $a_n$ depends from $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}$ you need set two values, e.g $a_1, a_2$

Comment: These are only initial conditions. This is how they are defined.

Comment: You only have to prove the case by induction with the initial conditions on $ a_0 $ and $ a_1 $.

Answer (score 3):

Strategy for this type of relation:

Solve $x^2 = 7x -10$

You get $x=2$ and $x=5$.

Then your solution must be in the form $a_n = c(2)^n+d(5)^n$, and you get $c$ and $d$ by substituting the initial values. So $3 = c+d$ and $3 = 2c+5d$. Solve this linear system.

I would explain why this works, but that would involve linear algebra.

The initial values are defined independently of the recurrence relation, since you can't use the relation to guess what $a_1$ and $a_2$ are.

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence states something that is implicit and may be the cause of your confusion:

The recurrence relation,

$$a_n = 7a_{n-1} - 10 a_{n-2}$$

Holds for all values of $n$ **greater than $1$**.

The equation says nothing about $a_0$ and $a_1$, so $a_0$ and $a_1$ can be anything. In your case, they equal $3$, and you can calculate $a_2$ by using the equation:

$$a_2 = 7a_1-10a_0=21-30=-9.$$

Comment: Well, somebody was trigger happy on the downvotes. Does he care to explain how the answers thus provided are wrong?